# Alterar nome de uma coluna da tabela com :nth-of-type

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando alterar o nome de uma coluna da minha tabela através do css, tentei algo como:

```
th#colunatableprod:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Produto"!important; }
```

Minha tabela:

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead class="black white-text">
        <tr>
            <th id="colunatableprod" scope="col">Produto</th>
            <th id="colunaindicelucro" scope="col">Índice de Lucro</th>
            <th id="colunamlpremium" scope="col">ML Premium</th>
            <th id="colunamlclassico" scope="col">ML Clássico</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

        <tr>
           <td>x</td>
           <td>y</td>
           <td>z</td>
           <td>aa</td>

       </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Com CSS vc não consegue alterar nós do DOM. Só com JavaScript.

Comment: consigo sim porque já faço isso com uma tabela, mas quero fazer com duas tabelas no mesmo css, já consegui mas não lembro agora.

Comment: Um id é único, não deveria usar nth-of-type(1) pra algo único.

Comment: Uma simples linha em JavaScript substitui o texto de um elemento com um id facilmente. Mas...

Comment: Ao meu ver pseudo-classes não serve para alterar nós. Vc pode até mascarar, mas não é esse o uso do recurso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que vc está com a visão errada de como funciona o `content` no `::after`, Ele não vai substituir o texto que está dentro da tag, ele vai adicionar o conteúdo do `content: ""` dentro da tag.

Então para funcionar da forma que vc pretende, primeiro vc tem que "apagar" o texto que está dentro da tag, para isso sugiro `font-size: 0`, mesmo que não seja semântico, pois vou considerar isso como um caso espscial ok.

Depois disso vc tem que criar o seu `content` e colocar o `font-size` de volta pois se não colocar o tamanho da fonte ele vai herdar o tamanho `0` que era o tamanho do "pai"

Agora veja como fica o código:

```css
#colunatableprod:nth-of-type(1) { font-size: 0; }
#colunatableprod:nth-of-type(1)::before { font-size: 12px; content: "Produto 1"; color:red; }
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="black white-text">
        <tr>
            <th id="colunatableprod" scope="col">Produto</th>
            <th id="colunaindicelucro" scope="col">Índice de Lucro</th>
            <th id="colunamlpremium" scope="col">ML Premium</th>
            <th id="colunamlclassico" scope="col">ML Clássico</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>z</td>
            <td>aa</td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @sam eu acho que o JS está ai para ser usado mesmo! Tem casos que ele resolve melhor que CSS, como nesse caso que o elemento tem ID. Melhor que usar font 0. Mas se a pessoa não souber JS tá ai uma solução com CSS rss. Eu acho que seria válido vc fazer um modelo com JS, vai ter gente que vai preferir dessa forma pode saber. Quanto mais opção melhor, a pergunta não precisa de só uma resposta :)

Comment: Pois é hugo... eu tomo negativo direto com sugestões que resolvem, mas não que seja o ideal. Postar respostas de baixa qualidade só porque "funciona" não é o ideal. O ideal, pelo menos o que tenho aprendido ao longo do tempo tomando os negativos, é sugerir ao AP a melhor forma em vez de postar algo ruim. Pra mim é estimular o AP leigo a usar recursos inapropriados para certos tipos de casos.

Comment: Ué,, ele pediu pra você postar uma resposta melhor, da maneira que você sugere ideal. Mas pelo visto você prefere ficar reclamando aheauheua

Comment: @Leticia Não estou reclamando. Estou apenas dizendo que esta não é a forma ideal e correta de fazer isso. Mas se quiser usar, desejo boa sorte.

Comment: @sam eu entendo o seu ponto de vista. Talve a forma de fazer não seja a ideial, mas ao mesmo tempo tenho certeza que a resposta serviu pelo menos para ela entender porque não deu certo. Quanto a melhor forma de fazer deixo por conta dela escolher o que melhor lhe serve. Talvez o JS sim seja a melhor opção, não deixe que um downvote te iniba de responder (se é que alguém vai votar contra), mas ponha seu ponto de vista e sua resposta, se for do agrado da comunidade, não só da autora da pergunta, com certeza vc ganha uns pontinhos.

Comment: Hugão, a visão não é ganhar "uns pontinhos", é postar respostas de qualidade, aí sim, os pontos fazem sentido.

Comment: @sam eu entendo, deixei a resposta explicando o problema com o content, mas infelizmente não tenho o conhecimento em js para dar uma explicação desse ponto de vista, o espaço esta ai aberto pra vc dar sua sugestão e de mais esclarecimentos da opção com js

Comment: Vou votar negativo porque acho a sua resposta inútil. OBS.: estou votando na resposta e não no autor dela.

Comment: @sam então completa a sua resposta explicando pq o que esta no content não substitui o texto que já esta dentro da tag e apenas faz um "apende". Se quiser pode pegar parte da minha resposta, ai eu posso apagar essa aqui

Answer (score 2):

Ao usar `nth-of-type(1)` em um `id` já está incorreto porque um `id` deve ser único na página (**[leia](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)**). Isso pressupõe que você quer usar o mesmo `id` em mais de um elemento.

Apenas com CSS você não irá conseguir alterar o conteúdo de um nó de texto. O CSS é usado para definir estilos visuais de elementos, não para alterar seus nós, até porque *pseudos-classes* não são nós de verdade (do grego, *pseudo* = falso). O máximo que você vai fazer é adicionar uma máscara sobre um elemento, e não alterar de fato o nó.

Para esse tipo de função de você usa o JavaScript, que já vem incluso no navegador. Basta usar o método `.textContent` (quando for apenas texto) ou `.innerHTML` (quando houver tags HTML):

```
document.getElementById("colunatableprod").textContent = "Produto Novo";
```

Comment: Ótima explicação eu não conhecia esse .textContent realmente resolve com uma linha